# C# WPF Color property doesn't apply to animations

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, button

I'm creating UI controls that I can use in all my projects.
I want to create a button where I can change the hover and pressed colors, but it just doesn't work. If I change the `TemplateBinding` to a `StaticResource` (line 24 and 30) it works fine, but if I do that then I can't change it anywhere else anymore.

I've been trying to fix this for a couple hours now and it for some reason just doesn't want to work and I can't find any instance of this anywhere online so this is my last option.

```cs
public class RoundButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HoverColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(HoverColor), typeof(Color), typeof(RoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(Color)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseDownColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MouseDownColor), typeof(Color), typeof(RoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(Color)));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(RoundButton), new PropertyMetadata(default(CornerRadius)));

    public Color HoverColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)GetValue(HoverColorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HoverColorProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public Color MouseDownColor
    {
        get
        {
            return (Color)GetValue(MouseDownColorProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MouseDownColorProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get
        {
            return (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
        }
    }

}
```

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:RoundButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HighlightBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DarkHighlightBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="HoverColor" Value="{StaticResource LightHighlightColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="MouseDownColor" Value="{StaticResource DarkHighlightColor}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:RoundButton}">
                <Border x:Name="Border" 
                        CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="MouseOver" To="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" />
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                    To="{TemplateBinding HoverColor}" Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                    To="{TemplateBinding MouseDownColor}" Duration="0:0:0.15" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Check the XAML Binding Errors window in Visual Studio, it might give you some hints

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville I did, I checked if the Color type was correct, I checked if the value is the same (it was), I triple checked the name, I changed it to a brush instead of a color. I checked everything like I always do before going to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Use Trigger instead of VisualState.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <!-- ... Your Animation ... -->
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterAction>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: You can handle button pressed state with a Trigger for the "IsPressed" property.